# In EF, call SaveChanges from SavingChanges event?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF 4.1 in an MVC 3 application.

My goal is to save all changes in another database for logging purposes.

I have implemented the `SavingChanges` event for an `EntityContext`. In that event, I'm extracting changes via the `GetObjectStateEntries()` , that works fine.

Then, I have another `EntityContext`, that works against a different model and database, for the logging. I create that Context, create logging Entities, adding them to the logging Context. All seems to work fine. Then when I call `SaveChanges()` on the logging context, Exception occurs, that says that I cant insert because the Id is null (which I know for sure that it isn't).

Does anyone know if it's impossible to achieve this? Am I missing some important detail?

Comment: You may have configured EF such that the `Id` of that table is auto incremented.

Comment: Thank you @Eranga , that was my case!

Answer (score 0):

The case was that I had used "Model first" in my logging model, and "DB first" in all other models. That resulted in the mistake that the EF configuration was expecting take care of the Id (GUID) itself, but I was trying to supply one myself. I deleted the entities from the model, and instead, imported them from the DB, and that solved the problem!

Thanks to @Eranga for setting me in the right direction.